# tar - file not found in tarball even though it is there

Tags: tar, qnx

### What I want to do

I just want to extract a backup version of a file for analysis, `/etc/net.cfg`, which is in a tar.

### What happens when I try

It fails, like so...

```
# tar -tf mytar.tar | grep net.cfg
/etc/net.cfg
# tar -xf mytar.tar /etc/net.cfg
tar: Removing leading `/' from absolute path names in the archive
# tar -xf mytar.tar etc/net.cfg
tar: etc/net.cfg: Not found in archive
tar: Error exit delayed from previous errors
```

### Troubleshooting I've tried

I made a separate test.tar which contains only a "test1.txt" and "test2.txt", and if I do `tar xf test.tar test1.txt` it correctly extracts just the 1 file I want. So extracting the single file is working in this other case.

### Question

Am I doing something wrong? **How do I extract from an *absolute path* like /etc/net.cfg out of the given tar file into the working directory?**

### Details

Operating system: QNX

Shell: /bin/ksh

Comment: It looks like `tar -xf mytar.tar /etc/net.cfg` already extracted the file to `etc/net.cfg`. Can you verify this?

Comment: @Freddy DOH! I read that as if it were telling me that I need to remove the leading '/', not that it was doing so itself. So I thought it was an error. Because of that, I didn't even bother to look! Yes, it is there!

Comment: Nice! Yes, absolute pathnames can be a bit confusing with `tar`. You may write your own answer :)

Comment: I was just about to hit submit on a meta question asking whether this Q&A is just a waste of space that should be deleted, then I realized that would just be compounding the problem.  >.< I'll just leave it for now.

Answer (score 2):

DOH! This is embarrassing. I read `tar: Removing leading '/' from absolute path names in the archive` thinking it was an error telling me that I need to remove the leading '/', which is why I then did it as just `etc/net.cfg`.

Apparently **it was not an error**. It was merely informational, telling me that it was taking that action itself, and it was proceeding appropriately. And **the file is there**.

I did not bother to check for the file because I was under the incorrect impression it was an error and that it wasn't even worth it to type ls to check.

So there's not really a problem after all! I am not sure if I should delete this Q&A or if someone else could make the same silly mistake and benefit from this.